# Does Safari control how cookies are read in non-Safari browsers on iOS?

Tags: ios, cookies, safari

With Apple's upcoming ITP 2.0 in Safari 12, I (along with most other affiliate marketers) have to deal with merchants who haven't switched to first-party cookies.

A friend pointed out that all web apps in iOS run on top of Safari. While this is known to affect JS/CSS and rendering, does this also affect how cookies are read?

Will a Chrome user be able to accept third-party cookies on iOS?